# How to fix black/negative background on livecharts chart in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

When adding a usercontrol at runtime (with a button click for example) that has a chart on, it causes the background of the chart to go black/negative.

When I add the usercontrol during the forms load it does not have this issue.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this one loads fine

        testingControl tc = new testingControl();
        this.Controls.Add(tc);
        tc.Location = new Point(470, 53);

        //......
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testingControl tc = new testingControl();
        this.Controls.Add(tc);
        //tc.Visible = false;
        //tc.Visible = true;
        tc.Location = new Point(0, 53);
    }
```

[image: image of problem]
I found out after some google searches, that hiding it and then setting it visible again kind of fixes it, but that seems a bit janky.
Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

P.S. the data that is in the chart I got from the 'livecharts' website, but the problem happens no matter if there is data or not.
The problem also happens on all charts.

Comment: weird. Did you try to specify the background color yourself? i.e. tc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

Comment: @JeffR. I set the background of UserControl that it was on to transparent and it actually worked! I am not sure why it was originally going black though. the backcolor property of the user control was not even set to black. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got similar problem & made few changes to get it fixed ,

Just change the chart visibility false

[image]

Change
Then , Make it visible on form load .

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     pieChart1.Visible = true;
    ....
    }
```

Hope this will help you !.